# Styling reacts material-ui tabs

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui

I just started to use reacts [material-ui](https://github.com/callemall/material-ui/blob/master/docs/src/app/components/pages/components/tabs.jsx) and I would like to customize some styles. For example changing tabs background color.

trying to use inlineStyle

like

```
<Tabs style={this.getStyles().tabs} > </Tabs>

    getStyles(){
        return {

          tabs: {
            backgroundColor: Colors.teal200
          },

          headline: {
            fontSize: '24px',
            lineHeight: '32px',
            paddingTop: '16px',
            marginBottom: '12px',
            letterSpacing: '0',
            fontWeight: Typography.fontWeightNormal,
            color: Typography.textDarkBlack,

          }
        }
    }
```

changes tabs content area but not the header.

[here](http://material-ui.com/#/customization/colors) we have some color attributes how we use it? The Docs gives no examples in this case.

How do I proceed?

Comment: Add some CSS to override the current styles?

Comment: simple use the provided color codes http://material-ui.com/#/customization/colors to change background color of the tab. But how?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The way I do it is to override the `<Tab>` style (if you have a controlled Tabs)

```js
render: function() {

  var styles = {
    default_tab:{
      color: Colors.grey500,
      backgroundColor: Colors.grey50,
      fontWeight: 400,
    },
    active_tab:{
      color: Colors.deepOrange700,
    }
  }

  styles.tab = []
  styles.tab[0] = styles.default_tab;
  styles.tab[1] = styles.default_tab;
  styles.tab[2] = styles.default_tab;
  styles.tab[this.state.slideIndex] = objectAssign({},   styles.tab[this.state.slideIndex], styles.active_tab);

  return (
    <Tabs>
      <Tab style={styles.tab[0]} label="Tab 0" value="0" />
      <Tab style={styles.tab[1]} label="Tab 1" value="1" />
      <Tab style={styles.tab[2]} label="Tab 2" value="2" />
    </Tabs>
  )
```

Though I think the better way is to have more props for Tabs/Tab so we can customize it.

Comment: Nice! Just update: **objectAssign** now is **Object.assign**

Answer (score 4):

So if anybody would face the same here is what I found

with  **ThemeManager** we can change style outputs

for example

```
ThemeManager.setTheme(ThemeManager.types.DARK);
```

changing specific style variables with `setPalette`

```
componentWillMount() {
        ThemeManager.setPalette({
          accent1Color: Colors.indigo50,
            primary1Color: "#474B4E",
            primary2Color: "#2173B3",
            primary3Color: "#A9D2EB",
            accent1Color: "#ED3B3B",
            accent2Color: "#ED2B2B",
            accent3Color: "#F58C8C"
        });
     }
```

Answer (score 2):

The most convenient way to customize the component is to simply apply plain old CSS by using the `className` attribute, since the capabilities of the provided `style` attributes are fairly limited.

Let's consider a straight forward example:

```
const MyAwesomeTabContainer = () => (
    <Tabs className="tabs-container">
        <Tab icon={<Person />} className="tab" />
        <Tab icon={<Content />} className="tab" />
    </Tabs>
);
```

The following **LESS** code (not CSS!) would allow you to customize the style according to your needs:

```
.tabs-container {
  >div:first-child { // modifies the background color
    background-color: #f6f6f6 !important;
  }

  >div:last-child { // changes the distance between tabs and content
    margin-top: 10px;
  }

  .tab {
    >div>div { // modifies the font size of the tab labels 
      font-size: 10px;

      svg { // modifies the color of SVG icons
        fill: #626262 !important;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Unfortunately it is necessary to apply a few `!important` statements because the style information of the component is set inline in code.

Answer (score 0):

For MUI (Material-UI V5) I wanted to add box shadow for tabs to look like this
[image]

You can use "component" property to pass elementType. ***The component used for the root node. Either a string to use a HTML element or a component.*** I used "Box" component:

```
import { Box } from '@mui/material';

...

<Tabs
  value={selectedTab}
  component={Box}
  boxShadow={3}
  onChange={changeSelectedTab}
  variant="fullWidth"
>
```

So now I can use all Box component properties like "boxShadow". I think it is more clean to style with properties of other MUI components.Be carefull only on "Caveat with inlining"
https://mui.com/material-ui/guides/composition/#component-prop

https://mui.com/material-ui/api/tabs/#props

Answer (score -2):

I wanted a class on the active tab, so here is a quick solution for that:

```
<Tabs className="pcd-tabs" onChange={this.handleChange}>
    <Tab className="pcd-tab pcd-tab0 pcd-tab-active" label="Chart" value={0} />
    <Tab className="pcd-tab pcd-tab1" label="Series" value={1} />
</Tabs>
```

than

```
handleChange = (value) => {
  document.getElementsByClassName('pcd-tab-active')[0].classList.remove('pcd-tab-active');
  document.getElementsByClassName('pcd-tab' + value)[0].classList.add('pcd-tab-active');
};
```